Adding Server Headers to Vite React Project isn't working
I have added the server headers as it is listed in the documentation but I the headers are not being added to the response of any requests from the app.
config file
Screenshot of a request. No headers shown.
request
Added the headers per the documentation and expected then to be added, but the headers never get added.

I see that your screenshot shows X-Powered-By header with value of ASP.NET. Are you sure that you are making request to your Vite server?

Is the API responsible for the the response headers? I thought the client handled that responsibility. If I have a .net core project with a react front end that calls an api I set the headers in that project as well.

Client responsible for Request headers, since it's making requests. Sever is responsible for Response headers, since it responds. You need to freshen up your HTTP knowledge

How you enable the server.https?
Try import basicSsl from '@vitejs/plugin-basic-ssl' and add basicSsl() in plugins
If you have your own certificate, you should add the server options in server.https which should be https.ServerOptions
https://vitejs.dev/config/server-options#server-https
